# Spring boot - angularjs using rest controller in http.get returns status 404

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

> I am trying to get a data from the server using JPA repository and spring 
>   restcontroller passed to the http.get method of the angularjs. but
>   when I view it in console.log, it shows: angular.js:11048 GET
>   http://127.0.0.1:8096/api/shipmentcount/sample 404 (Not Found). What
>   seems to be wrong?
>
> master.controller.js - function

```
    $scope.countTrips = function() {
    $http.get("/api/shipmentcount/sample").success(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
}

$scope.countTrips();
```

> ShipmentResources.java - requestmapping with a method get

```
@RequestMapping(value="/shipmentcount/sample", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Shipment> getshipmentCount() {
    return shipmentRepository.findAll();
}
```

> ShipmentRepository.java

```
    package com.pahrsek.smartfleet.repository;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.pahrsek.smartfleet.dto.ShipmentSummary;
import com.pahrsek.smartfleet.model.Company;
import com.pahrsek.smartfleet.model.Customer;
import com.pahrsek.smartfleet.model.Shipment;
import com.pahrsek.smartfleet.model.Shipment.Status;
import com.pahrsek.smartfleet.model.Vehicle;

@Repository
public interface ShipmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Shipment, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Shipment>{



    @Query( value="select new com.pahrsek.smartfleet.dto.ShipmentSummary(ship.status as status, "
            + "count(ship.id) as recordCount "
            + ") from Shipment ship where ship.company=?1 and ship.dateCreated>=?2 AND ship.dateCreated <=?3  group by ship.status")
    public List<ShipmentSummary> summaryByStatus(Company company, Date from, Date to);

    public List<Shipment> findFirst10ByVehicle(Vehicle vehicle);

    public List<Shipment> findByVehicle(Vehicle vehicle);

    public Shipment findByIdAndCompany(Long id, Company company);

    public List<Shipment> findByStatus(Status status);

    public List<Shipment> findByCustomerAndDepotAndOriginAndTypeAndCommodityTypeAndDateCreatedAfter(Customer customer, String depot, String origin, String type, String commodityType, Date dateCreated);

}
```

> And this is the log
>   [image]
>
> This is the Shipment.java

```
    package com.pahrsek.smartfleet.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;


/**
 * Delivery of goods
 * @author JRDomingo
 *
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="shipment")
public class Shipment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long id;

    @Column(name="booking_number",unique=true)
    public String bookingNumber;

    @Column(name="wb_number")
    public String wbNumber;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="vehicle_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    public Vehicle vehicle;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    public Customer customer;

    public String origin;

    public String depot;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="vendor_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    public Vendor vendor;

    public String type;

    @Column(name="commodity_type")
    public String commodityType;

    @Column(name="truck_type")
    public String truckType;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public Status status;

    @Column(name="delivery_date")
    public Date deliveryDate;

    @Column(name="fuel_po")
    public String fuelPo;

    @Column(name="client_ref_no")
    public String clientReferenceNumber;

    public String remarks;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="driver_id",referencedColumnName="id")
    public Personnel driver;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="helper1_id",referencedColumnName="id")
    public Personnel helper1;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="helper2_id",referencedColumnName="id")
    public Personnel helper2;


    public enum Status{
        New, Dispatched, Delivered, Completed, Cancelled
    }

    /******
     * ACTUAL DATES IMPLEMENTED
     ******/
    @Column(name="date_created")
    public Date dateCreated;

    @Column(name="date_dispatched")
    public Date dateDispatched;

    @Column(name="date_completed")
    public Date dateCompleted;

    @Column(name="date_cancelled")
    public Date dateCancelled;

    @Column(name="date_received")
    public Date dateReceived;

    @Column(name="farthest_destination")
    public String farthestDestination;

    @Column(name="client_rate")
    public Double clientRate;

    @Column(name="is_sub_con")
    public boolean isSubCon;

    @Column(name="sub_con_rate")
    public Double subConRate;

    @Column(name="fuel")
    public Double fuel;

    @Column(name="fuel_amount")
    public Double fuelAmount;

    @Column(name="route_code")
    public String routeCode;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name="dispatched_odometer_id",referencedColumnName="id")
    public RegularOdometerUsage dispatchedOdometer;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name="delivered_odometer_id",referencedColumnName="id")
    public RegularOdometerUsage deliveredOdometer;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name="completed_odometer_id",referencedColumnName="id")
    public RegularOdometerUsage completedOdometer;


    /**
     * index 0 = Driver , index 1 = Helper1, index 2 = Helper2
     */
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="shipment",targetEntity=PersonnelRate.class)
    public List<PersonnelRate> personnelRates = new ArrayList<PersonnelRate>();

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    public Company company;


    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="prepared_user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    public User preparedBy;


    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="customer_invoice", referencedColumnName="id")
    public CustomerInvoice customerInvoice;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="trucker_settlement", referencedColumnName="id")
    public TruckerSettlement truckerSettlement;

}
```

> What am I trying to do is to get the status column in the table shipment. I tried creating a rest controller and integrated it with angularjs for front end. I cant find what is causing the problem. I think it cant find the the controller /api/shipmentcount/sample. I am new to spring boot. and This is my first time developing it. What I am trying to do with the rest controller is I want to get a data from the server to be used in the charts in my dashboard. I used chart.js for my charts.
>
> This is my complete ShipmentResource.java - controller

```
    package com.pahrsek.smartfleet.web.rest;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.Direction;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.pahrsek.smartfleet.dto.ShipmentDTO;
import com.pahrsek.smartfleet.dto.ShipmentSummary;
import com.pahrsek.smartfleet.dto.SimpleVehicle;
import com.pahrsek.smartfleet.model.Company;
import com.pahrsek.smartfleet.model.Shipment;
import com.pahrsek.smartfleet.model.Shipment.Status;
import com.pahrsek.smartfleet.model.ShipmentCharge;
import com.pahrsek.smartfleet.model.Vehicle;
import com.pahrsek.smartfleet.repository.PersonnelRateRepository;
import com.pahrsek.smartfleet.repository.PersonnelRepository;
import com.pahrsek.smartfleet.repository.ShipmentChargeRepository;
import com.pahrsek.smartfleet.repository.ShipmentRepository;
import com.pahrsek.smartfleet.security.SecurityUtils;
import com.pahrsek.smartfleet.service.ShipmentService;
import com.pahrsek.smartfleet.web.rest.filter.ShipmentFilter;
import com.pahrsek.smartfleet.web.rest.filter.VehicleFilter;
import com.pahrsek.smartfleet.web.rest.util.PaginationUtil;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ShipmentResource {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ShipmentResource.class);

    @Autowired
    ShipmentService shipmentService;

    @Autowired
    ShipmentRepository shipmentRepository;

    @Autowired
    PersonnelRateRepository personnelRateRepository;

    @Autowired
    PersonnelRepository personnelRepository;

    @Autowired
    ShipmentChargeRepository shipmentChargeRepository;

//  @Value("#{'${jentec.shipmentTypes}'.split(',')}")
    public List<String> shipmentTypes;

    @Value("${jentec.shipment.footer}")
    public String shipmentFooter;

    @RequestMapping(value="/shipments", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public void create(@RequestBody ShipmentDTO request){
        Company company = SecurityUtils.getCurrentCompany();
        String depot = null;

        Shipment shipment = shipmentService.save(request,company);
        logger.info("shipment saved:{}",shipment);
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/shipments/{shipmentId}/status", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public void saveDispatch(@PathVariable("shipmentId")Long shipmentId, @RequestBody UpdateStatusDTO request){
        shipmentService.updateStatus(shipmentId, request);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/shipmentcount", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Shipment> getshipmentCount() {
        return shipmentRepository.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/shipments", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<ShipmentDTO>> list(@RequestParam(value="page", defaultValue="1") int page, 
            @RequestParam(value="per_page", defaultValue="10") int size,
            @RequestParam(value="sort", defaultValue="id") String sort,
            @RequestParam(value="direction", defaultValue="DESC") Direction direction,
            HttpServletRequest request) throws URISyntaxException{
        Pageable pageRequest = PaginationUtil.generatePageRequest(page, size, new Sort(direction,sort));
        Company company = SecurityUtils.getCurrentCompany();
        String depot = SecurityUtils.getCurrentDepot();
        Page<Shipment> pageResult = shipmentRepository.findAll(new ShipmentFilter(request, company, depot), pageRequest);
        HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(pageResult, "/api/shipments", page, size);
        List<ShipmentDTO> shipmentDTOs = new ArrayList<ShipmentDTO>();
        for(Shipment shipment:pageResult.getContent()){
            shipmentDTOs.add(new ShipmentDTO(shipment, true));
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<List<ShipmentDTO>>(shipmentDTOs, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/shipments/summary", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<ShipmentSummary> getSummary(@RequestParam("from") String from, @RequestParam("to") String to) throws URISyntaxException{
        Company company = SecurityUtils.getCurrentCompany();
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        try {
            return shipmentRepository.summaryByStatus(company, df.parse(from), df.parse(to));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            logger.error("Cannot parse date",e);
            return new ArrayList<ShipmentSummary>();
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/shipmentTypes")
    public List<String> getShipmentTypes(){
        return shipmentTypes;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/shipments/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<ShipmentDTO> get(@PathVariable("id") Long id) throws URISyntaxException{
        Company company = SecurityUtils.getCurrentCompany();
        Shipment shipment = shipmentRepository.findOne(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<ShipmentDTO>(new ShipmentDTO(shipment, true), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/shipments/{id}/charges", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<ShipmentCharge> getCharges(@PathVariable("id") Long shipmentId){
        return shipmentChargeRepository.findByShipmentId(shipmentId);
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/shipmentFooter", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public Map<String,String> getShipmentFooter(){
        Map<String,String> footer = new HashMap<String,String>();
        footer.put("message", shipmentFooter);
        return footer;
    }

    public static class UpdateStatusDTO{
        public Status status;
        public Date date;
        //for delivery date
        public Date deliveryDate;
        public Integer odometer;
        public Double clientRate;
        public String remarks;
        public String farthestDestination;
        public Double fuel;
        public String fuelPo;
        public Double fuelAmount;
        public String clientReference;
        public String routeCode;
    }
}
```

Comment: if you hit `http://yourhost:8080/shipmentcount/sample` do you see the expected response ?

Comment: Also, can you post the complete controller code. Is it possible you forgot to annotate it with @RequestMapping("/api")?

Comment: Sudakatux - No. It redirects me to route "/". and return a 404 error status.

Answer (score 0):

from what I see in your question it seems you have different paths.
you call: `"/api/shipmentcount/sample"` in angularJS but you have declared: `"/shipmentcount/sample"` in `@RequestMapping`. You are missing `"/api"` part.

check if your controller has an annotation: `@RequestMapping(value="/api")`

if not, check in your appication.properties file if you have something like: `server.contextPath=/api`

if neither, you can correct your endpoint method like so:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/api/shipmentcount/sample", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Shipment> getshipmentCount() {
    return shipmentRepository.findAll();
}
```

also, if angularJS runs on different domain or port you need to provide the server domain and port.

for example if angular runs on http://127.0.0.1:4200 and your server at http://127.0.0.1:8096, you need to correct it like so:

```
$http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8096/api/shipmentcount/sample").success(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

also you need to allow CORS in order to make requests from different domains. You do that with this annotation above your method: `@CrossOrigin`

I hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer Vasilis Antonakis. But it is still returning the angular.js:11048 GET http://127.0.0.1:8096/api/shipmentcount/sample 404 (Not Found). I have provided the complete code on my controller. Thank you.

Comment: OK :) I can see that in your controller you have `@RequestMapping(value="/shipmentcount", method=RequestMethod.GET)` in your method, not `@RequestMapping(value="/shipmentcount/sample", method=RequestMethod.GET)` :) is that correct?

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, I accidentally erased that after copying it. But, it is still returning me angular.js:11048 GET http://127.0.0.1:8096/api/shipmentcount/sample 404 (Not Found).

Comment: It seems there is some confusion with the declaration and the calling of the end point :) double check that the calling url is matching the mapped one :) everything else seems ok